# TypeError: navbarUserInfoComponent[0] is undefined in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am currently writing a jasmine test case to test that a logout menu component works correctly.

Here is my TS file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog' 
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RecursiveAstVisitor } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

//import { faChalkboard, faExclamationTriangle, IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/shared/authentication.service';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/shared/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar-user-info',
  templateUrl: './navbar-user-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar-user-info.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarUserInfoComponent implements OnInit {


  // notificationIcon: IconDefinition;
  // //RID Icon
  // faExclamationTriangle = faExclamationTriangle;
  // //Whiteboard Icon
  // faChalkboard = faChalkboard;

  totalNotifications = 0;
  user;
  employee;
  expanded: any[][] = new Array();
  interval;
  pageRoute = '/dynamic';


  tooltipPosition = "above"

  constructor(
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private loginService: LoginService,
    //private userService: UserAPI,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Initializing: header-user-info.component.ts")

    console.log(this.authenticationService.getEmployeeId());
    console.log(this.authenticationService.getUserName());
    this.user=this.authenticationService.getUserName();
  }



  logout() {
    this.loginService.logout();
  }

}
```

This is the html file:

```
<div class="nav-div" *ngIf="authenticationService.isLoggedIn() | async as loggedIn" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center"
  fxLayoutGap="12px">

  <div *ngIf="user"> 
    <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
      <div class="user-profile-details">User: {{user}}</div>
      <!-- <div class="user-profile-details">Role: {{user?.role?.roleName}}</div> -->
      <!--<div class="user-profile-details">Company: {{user?.companyNm}}</div> -->
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" class="no-hover">
    <!--  <mat-icon class="material-icons">account_circle</mat-icon> -->
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg material-icons"></i>
    </button>
</div> 
</div>
```

and this is the Spec file based on a course on Jasmine testing I had taken.
(This is what is currently in the Spec file)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NavbarUserInfoComponent } from './navbar-user-info.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/shared/authentication.service';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/shared/login.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { MatMenuItem } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export class mockAuthentication{
  getUserInfo(){
    return "1";
  };
  getUserRole(){
    return "admin";
  };
  getUserName(){
    return "Test User";
  };
  isLoggedIn(){
    return true;
  };
};
describe('NavbarUserInfoComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarUserInfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarUserInfoComponent>;
  let mockLoginService, mockMatDialog, mockRouter; //, mockAuthentication;
  let USER;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
     USER = [
      {id:1, name:'Test User', role: 'admin'}
    ]
    //mockAuthentication = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getUserInfo','getUserRole','getUserName','isLoggedIn']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ NavbarUserInfoComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthentication},
        {provide: LoginService, useValue: mockLoginService},
        {provide: MatDialog, useValue: mockMatDialog},
        {provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter}
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarUserInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should test a click of the logout button', () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'logout').and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const link = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#btn-Logout');
    link.click();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
});
```

My question is when this runs I am getting this result.
(I have update to show the current error messages)

[image]

My question is, Why is it saying the 'navbarUserInfoComponent[0]' is undefined?

if I take the [0] off, I am getting a message that 'triggerEventHandler' is undefined.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not catching the HTML element correctly. Try putting `id` to get the element easily

```
<button id="logout-btn" mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

In `spec` file:

```
  it('should test a click of the logout button', () => {
    spyOn(component,'logout').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const btn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#logout-btn');
    btn.click();
    expect(component.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
   )}
```

Update:

define `user` by creating  a mock as

```
class MockAuthenticationService{
   getUserName(){
     return "hero"
  }
  // and other methods as well
}
```

and in `TestBed` try:

```
 // ......
 providers: [
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService},
```

Comment: Ok, the HTML page was written by another person. I have made these changes: in html`<button id="btn-Logout" mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">Logout</button>` in spec:`  it('should test a click of the logout button', () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'logout').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#btn-Logout');
    link.click();
    expect(component.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })'
I am getting `TypeError: link is null` as a result

Comment: I didn't put the right quotes around my updated spec file. `it('should test a click of the logout button', () => {
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'logout').and.callThrough();
fixture.detectChanges();
const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#btn-Logout');
link.click();
expect(component.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
` This should show it correctly

Comment: @EricLommatsch: Can you try `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#logout-btn');` please and let me know. I have updated the answer

Comment: I am still getting the same making this change.

Comment: @EricLommatsch : Can you make sure that `user` is defined because there is an `*ngIf` condition to render this button. Check the new updated answer

Comment: I have changed the mock for the AuthenticationService from `mockAuthentication = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getUserInfo','getUserRole','getUserName','isLoggedIn']);` to this `@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar-user-info',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class mockAuthentication{
  getUserInfo(){
    return "1";
  };
  getUserRole(){
    return "admin";
  };
  getUserName(){
    return "Test User";
  };
  isLoggedIn(){
    return true;
  };
};` I am now getting these errors when the test runs `TypeError: this.authenticationService.getUserName is not a function`

Comment: I am also getting the same error in the `it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });` test.  That was working before.

Comment: @EricLommatsch : why are you using `@Component` for `mock` ? Mock the service and not the component as I have shown. Can you please put the "not working" spec file in the question as an `UPDATE` section. Its difficult to read the code in comment section. Refer https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 which I have written\

Comment: I have just updated my original post to show things as they stand at this time. I am new to writing test cases and I had looked at an example that was not the right one for writing the mock.

Comment: Based on the link you provided I tried to rewrite the mockAuthentication to `export class mockAuthentication{
  getUserInfo(){
    //return "1";
    return of({
      data: [
        { id: 1, firstName: "Test", lastName: "User", roleName: "admin"}
      ]
    });
  };
  getUserRole(){
    return "admin";
  };
  getUserName(){
    return of({
      data: [ 
        { id:1, fullName: "Test User" }
      ]
    })
  };
  isLoggedIn(){
    return true;
  };
};
` After doing this I am still getting `TypeError: this.authenticationService.getUserName is not a function`

Comment: @EricLommatsch: There is small mistake that you have done. Change `useValue` to `useClass`  for `AuthenticationService` mock service as I earlier suggested in the answer. That should fix it.  It takes time to learn it. Feel free to  update the comments if `useClass` fixes the issue :)

Comment: Thanks to this I am now finally able to get this test to pass.  In the process I have learned which is a good thing.  What got me to where I needed to be was both the answer and the comments.

Comment: @EricLommatsch: Cool, There are some good collection in the bottom page of https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7. Take a look and happy learning. Feel free to upvote the answer as well :)